# Input Fields are not Showing on Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dom

My contact form is not working correctly. When I enter wrong data, all is working as it should, but when data is correct the `input fields` are not showing. I need to click them with mouse and then they start showing.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function() {
        if($('#register').find('.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok').length > 0){
            $('#name-152').val('Full Name').show('slow');
            $('#email-152').val('Email').show('slow');
            $('#phone-152').val('Phone Number').show('slow');
        }
    });
```

please note that class `.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok`appears only when form is filled submitted and correctly. What confuses me the most is that `.find` cannot find the descendant `.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok`, and it is one of the descendants.. I have tested it with `console.log();` and `alert();`

This is Wordpress plugin - Contact Form 7

Any ideas?

Comment: Show the markup you are using

Comment: Can you share executable demo or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: Is `register` the form's ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Contact Form 7" plug-in acts on the submission event to do its magic, like manipulating styles and replacing the standard form submission behaviour by an AJAX-style submission.

As this might happen after the button's `click` event, and probably on the form's `submit` event, your code runs too soon.

One way to get around this, is to delay the execution of your code with `setTimeout`:

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if ($('#register').find('.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok').length) {
            $('#name-152').val('Full Name').show('slow');
            $('#email-152').val('Email').show('slow');
            $('#phone-152').val('Phone Number').show('slow');
        }
    }, 100);
});
```